# View database records via listview itemclick

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, listview

I am new to Android and I want to know how to view mySQL database records in another activity via listview itemclick but it depends on the database primary key of the selected item in the listview.

In other words, since the items in the listview are parsed from a database, each item will have a primary key. When you click that item, the user will go to another activity to view details about that particular item based on its primary key. How can I start a new activity based on the primary key of the list item selected? Sample code would be much appreciated.

Comment: you mean you want the listitem clicked value from database on second activity right?

Comment: I'm interpreting this as you're looking for a way to view details about an item that was clicked. For example, if you have a listview of bank accounts, when the user clicks one they should be taken to a screen that shows all transactions for that account, so you need to know the primary key of the account that was clicked?

Comment: @McAdam331 Actually i don't really want to know the primary key, but with your example that's what I wanted :) really like that

Comment: @JeffreyZamucoOliveras Okay. Well, as I'm sure you've seen, my example can be tweaked slightly to pull whatever piece of information from the item you need. :)

Comment: @McAdam331 Yeah, Thank You very much :) I'm searching for other resources now.

Comment: @McAdam331 
 
how about this?, for example you have a listview, abd when you click an item the title will set in action bar.

Comment: @JeffreyZamucoOliveras That can be done easily. Have you gotten it to work?

Comment: @McAdam331 yeah i did a research about it and apply it, but still :( can't get to it

Comment: @JeffreyZamucoOliveras Are you using a Fragment? If it's all in the same activity you can try `getSupportActionBar.setTitle(dataSource.get(position).getName())` inside your onItemClickListener. If you're using a Fragment, you may need a callback to the Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer may depend on what kind of adapter you're using. If you're using a CursorAdapter, you'll have to get the cursor at the position clicked, and read the id value:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) mAdapter.getItem(position);
        long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id");
    }
});
```

If you're not using a cursor adapter, you can just change those two lines to match whatever object you're using:

```
Object myObject = (Object) mAdapter.getItem(position);
long id = myObject.getIdentifier();
```

Once you have this information, you can use it as `Extras` to an `Intent` to start another activity to do the stuff you've mentioned. From what you've described you're looking for a master-detail flow, there are plenty of resources out there explaining it.

Comment: @JeffreyZamucoOliveras best of luck! If you have more detailed questions, please let me know.